# How to make this functional-style code more performant while maintaining its syntax

Tags: c#, f#, functional-programming, ocaml

I would like to write this operation

```
Matrix.Multiply(source,target)
target.Add(offsets)
```

in this mathematical style

```
target = Matrix * source + offsets;
```

However, I'm also concerned about performance. (In fact, the above operation will be run in a tight loop.) I don't want to create a new vector for each matrix-vector multiplication and another new vector for the vector addition.

How can I implement the above operation in C# or F# (or any functional language that you know) so that style and performance can be both achieved?

Sorry for this naive question. I'm sure this desire is so fundamental.

Comment: Why do you need it in functional form? You could achieve your aim by dynamically creating Linq Expressions & compiling them, but this is HUGELY more complex.

Comment: Is the `Matrix` class yours?

Comment: Yes, Matrix can be anything I want.

Comment: @BrendanHill, the functional form is more readable and closer to the mathematical description.

Answer (score 10):

A well-known technique, that is for example at the heart of the [Repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) library of high-performance numeric arrays, is to define on top of the basic "2D array of integer" structure a higher-level data structure that *delays* the operations you want to perform, along with an intepretation/normalization function that will finally perform those operations, applying any optimization it deems profitable.

Concretely, in your example, and I think most current answers have missed this, you want `A * B + C` to be rewritten not into

```
add(multiply(A,B), C)
```

or in OO styl
e

```
A.multiply(B).add(C)
```

but instead

```
multiply_and_add(A,B,C)
```

where `multiply_and_add` is a specialez, lower-level operation that does both operations at once and is more optimized. Similarly, it is well-known that for arbitrary matrices `A, B, C, D`, the product `A * B * C * D` may be more efficiently computed as `A * ((B * C) * D)` rather than `A * (B * (C * D)))`, depending on the operand dimensions. So a purely local approach (expressing each operation on arrays of integers) does not work, you need expression-global rewrites for optimal efficiency -- as done by the hackish template libraries in C++.

The solution is to move from `int array array` to a refined datatype, for example:

```
type matrix =
  | Raw of int array array
  | Add of matrix * matrix
  | Mult of matrix * matrix
```

and then provide a `eval : matrix -> int array array` function that "interprets" those matrix descriptions (in essence abstract syntax trees of matrix operations) by possibly applying domain-specific optimizations. For a naive example:

```
let rec eval = function
  | Raw m -> m
  | Add(Mult(a,b), c) | Add(c, Mult(a,b)) ->
    multiply_and_add (eval a) (eval b) (eval c)
  | Add (a, b) -> add (eval a) (eval b)
  | Mult (a, b) -> mult (eval a) (eval b)
```

You can then define the syntactic sugar of your liking to make the `matrix` constructors easier to read.

```
module Matrix = struct
  let (!) m = Raw m
  let (+) a b = Add (a, b)
  let (*) a b = Mult (a, b)
end

let ... = eval Matrix.(!A * !B + !C)
```

Answer (score 2):

Making the assumption that the `Matrix` class is yours, you can overload the operators:

```
public static Matrix operator *(Matrix x, Matrix y)
{
    return Matrix.Multiply(x, y);
}

public static Matrix operator +(Matrix x, OffsetsType offsets)
{
    x.Add(offsets);
    return x;
}
```

So, this expression (which is a modification of the one in your question because in your question you are multiplying `Matrix` by `source` and that doesn't make sense):

```
target = target * source + offsets;
```

broken out, would look like this:

```
var z = Matrix.Multiply(target, source);
z.Add(offsets);
target = z;
```

Comment: 1) you need a return in your `operator +` 2) it's static so you need a `Matrix x` parameter, and use `x.Add` instead of `this`

Answer (score 0):

If performance is your largest concern, the fastest way to do this is to define Matrix as a struct if it isn't already, then use ref/out parameters instead of ones that create a lot of copies.

```
public void Multiply(ref Matrix left, ref Matrix right, out Matrix result)
```

This is the approach taken by a number of C# game/graphics frameworks.

- [MonoGame](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Matrix.cs)
- [OpenTK](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/blob/master/Source/OpenTK/Math/Matrix4.cs)
- [SharpDX](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX/Matrix.cs)

There's also this very interesting article about optimizing OpenTK's matrix multiplication, which might give you ideas about how to further speed up matrix operations: [Making OpenTK matrix multiplication faster](http://www.edais.co.uk/blog/?p=27)

Of course, if you matrix class isn't of a fixed size, then this information is largely useless.

Answer (score -1):

You can create custom operators for your classes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx

This gives you the syntax you want, but still functional programming behind the scenes. Performance will be no different since .NET will just compile your operator-using code to be function-calling instead.

Comment: Why the downvote? No offense taken, just want to understand the reason.